# If Then Else, troubleshooting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

```
private void DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object then = null;
            if (this.DropDown.Text == "Thing1")
                _ = then;
                    Find.Enabled = false;
            else
                    Find.Enabled = true;
        }
```

How do I get this to work? If Thing 1 is selected I want the button to be disabled and if Thing1 isn't selected I want the button to be enabled. The code worked before I added the else.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an if/else for this. You can just set the property to the `boolean` result of comparing the `DropDown.Text` value to your expected value.

```cs
private void DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Find.Enabled = (this.DropDown.Text == "Thing1");
}
```

For your reference as well, there is no `then` keyword in C#.

Answer (score 1):

When you use more than one command, you need to enclose them in {}.

Answer (score 1):

You change your code to:

```
private void DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object then = null;
        if (this.DropDown.Text == "Thing1")
        {
            _ = then;
                Find.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
                Find.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your if-else blocks are not surrounded by curly braces. Therefore, only the line after `if` is considered the if-block. To your compiler, your code looks like:

```cs
if (this.DropDown.Text == "Thing1")
{
    _ = then;
}
Find.Enabled = false;
else
{
    Find.Enabled = true;
}
```

If you don't care about `_` and `then`, you could simplify your whole method to one line:

```cs
Find.Enabled = (DropDown.Text == "Thing1");
```

Comment: This won't compile. You'd need to include the `Find.Enabled = false;` between the braces.

Comment: Yes, it won't compile. That's what the OP wrote, added braces to explain what they wrote. As I have written above.

Comment: I see, I misread your answer. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: No worries. I guess I could've written it more clearly.